# Can I Mark My External HDD As Unbootable?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

When I start my computer, I think it tries to boot from my external HDD which is connected via USB.

The reason I think this is because when I open the Disks utility my external drive shows up as sda but my actual primary drive with the OS shows up as sdb. Also the external drive is mounted by default when the PC starts up.

I purposely have my BIOS set to boot from USB first, and then boot the internal hard drives second.

I'm worried though that always trying to boot from my external drive is bad for the drive. I'm not sure, but I'm worried. I would prefer if the OS would boot from the internal drive and leave the external drive unmounted until I want to access it. Is this possible without changing the BIOS?

Comment: You can use gparted, to check if your drive has the boot flag enabled, but, i think that, the BIOS always will try to boot from the USB devices first if you configured it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to change whether a drive is mounted at startup or not without making any changes to BIOS.  I would consider, however, whether the concern about "boot[ing] from my external drive" is warranted.  When it comes to booting the PC, either a bootable operating system is found on the particular drive and, as such, is booted or it is not.  Nothing is hurt by this check at startup time.  I should also point out that booting off a drive and mounting that drive in an operating system booted from another drive are unrelated -- the occurrence of the latter does not indicate the occurrence of the former.

If you really feel like you want to disable this mounting at startup, however, there are two ways that the drive may be mounted.  One is through the more traditional `/etc/fstab` file.  I would first check the `/etc/fstab` file and remove the line that mounts the secondary drive, if it exists.  A quick Google search returned [this guide](http://www.linuxstall.com/fstab/), but many others exist.

The second way it may be mounted (and disabled from doing so) is through the Disks utility.  In the Disks utility, click the drive for which you want to disable the automatic mount, click the partition on that drive that is being mounted, click the gear icon, and click "Edit Mount Options."  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qwr3e7oPN0) could be helpful in seeing where the options exist to enable and disable the mounting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The concern about booting from external drives might be warranted in case we are talking about a laptop. The possibility of theft is an concern there, and protecting against booting from external drives is one step in protecting personal or otherwise confidential data on the computer.

Comment: If the computer realizes it cannot be booted off the external drive, and boots off the internal drive instead, shouldn't the internal drive be labeled as sda?? Why is the external drive labeled as sda, and the internal drive labeled as sdb? Furthermore, in my fstab file the only visible drive is sdb. I cannot change the settings of the external drive from the fstab file.

Comment: The decision of the OS regarding which drive to set as `sda` and `sdb` is based on what order the drives are reported by the BIOS and based on UDEV rules, as far as I know.  These can be reassigned, as described by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18423187/1003560), but I will repeat the recommendations of the answer that it is "dangerous business for the novice" and probably not necessary.